# Jar is perfectly running when run via UNIX Script, but gives Null pointer when run via Crons

Tags: java, unix, cron

I am facing a strange issue , that I am able to run my jar perfectly fine when directly running through UNIX script, but when same UNIX script is triggered via crons it gives me error.

My UNIX scirpt is something like this : myUnix.ksh

```
/path/to/java -jar /some/path/to/myJar.jar runTimeArgumentPathToMypropertyFile
```

The above code if run via UNIX command : `bash /path/to/my/script/myUnix.ksh` runs perfectly fine.

But when I trigger the script via crons for ex : `9 10 * * * bash /path/to/my/script/myUnix.ksh`
it gives me Null pointer exception.

My code use property file to load certain configurable Items, the path to which I pass as run time argument.

The line which gives me null pointer exception is where my code access property file values. **Its gives me no File Not found exception.** so it seems my code has found the file and loaded it too.

Upon debugging I found that my property object has no key value pairs when run via crons. I have checked permission of all files involved in this process as 0777. Still not got solution.

here is the code which I used to load the properties file :

```
/**
 * Used to initialise PM repository
 * @param keyNotCaseSensitive
 * @param absolutePathToMasterFile
 * @param filter
 * @throws GLDUtilException
 */
public static void initialize(boolean keyNotCaseSensitive, String absolutePathToMasterFile, String filter) throws GLDUtilException{
    if(!initialized){
        Map<String, String> mapOfFiles = GenParser.generateMapUsingPropertyFile(keyNotCaseSensitive, absolutePathToMasterFile);
        map= new LinkedHashMap<String, PropertyMap>();
        listOfPropertyMapNames= new ArrayList<String>();

        if(filter!=null){
            if(keyNotCaseSensitive){
                filter= filter.toUpperCase();
            }
            String[] fl = filter.split(UtilConstants.COMMA);
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(fl));
            for(String key : mapOfFiles.keySet()){
                for(String flt: set){
                    if(keyNotCaseSensitive){
                        key=key.toUpperCase();
                    }
                    if(key.contains(flt.trim())){
                        PropertyMap pm = new PropertyMap(keyNotCaseSensitive, key, mapOfFiles.get(key));
                        map.put(key, pm);
                        listOfPropertyMapNames.add(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(String key : mapOfFiles.keySet()){
                PropertyMap pm = new PropertyMap(keyNotCaseSensitive, key, mapOfFiles.get(key));
                map.put(key, pm);
                listOfPropertyMapNames.add(key);
            }
        }
        PMRepo.keyNotCaseSensitive=keyNotCaseSensitive;
        PMRepo.initialized=true;
    }
}
```

And generic parser :

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param keyNotCaseSensitive
 * @param absolutePathToFile
 * @return
 * @throws GLDUtilException
 *             UtilConstants.ERR0001,ERR0002
 */
public static Map<String, String> generateMapUsingPropertyFile(boolean keyNotCaseSensitive,String absolutePathToFile) throws GLDUtilException {
    Scanner fileScanner=null;
    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(absolutePathToFile));
        Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if(line.contains(UtilConstants.EQ)){
                String[] pair =line.split(UtilConstants.EQ);
                                    System.out.println(line);
                if(keyNotCaseSensitive){
                    result.put(pair[0].trim().toUpperCase(), pair[1].trim());
                }else{
                    result.put(pair[0].trim(), pair[1].trim());
                }

            }
        }
        return result;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new GLDUtilException(MessageFormat.format(UtilConstants.ERR0001, absolutePathToFile), e);
    }finally{
        if(fileScanner!=null){
            fileScanner.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Any direction or has somebody faces similar issue?

Comment: Show your code (always show your code when posting a question. Explanations are nowhere near as clear as hard code). Especially the part where you load the properties.

Comment: Is there a reason you implemented property parsing yourself instead of using the `Properties` class or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I want complete control on how key value pairs are generated. I have future plans of extending my parser class to allow me hold HTML, XML , JSON data as values and easily Marshall them to standard objects.
This is frequent requirement for many of my projects and I have created a one Utility jar, which I keep updating myself. So with this future extension in my mind I made my own custom parser.

Comment: Well, if you want to reinvent the wheel. So is the path to your property file an absolute path?

Comment: Yes Path to my property file is absolute path.

Comment: Include the stacktrace in your post (and indicate the line of the NPE in your code).

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for you help, but I have indeed now sorted this out with a alternative. Instead of scanner I used BufferedReader and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about the user context your code is running in. I suppose your cron is running within a different user context than your script.

Comment: HI no my cron is running with the same user ID I ran my script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
the issue was with the Scanner, in the generic parser.
I simply replaced the Scanner

```
public static Map<String, String> generateMapUsingPropertyFile(boolean keyNotCaseSensitive,String absolutePathToFile) throws GLDUtilException {
    Scanner fileScanner=null;
    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(absolutePathToFile));
        Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
```

With BufferedReader like this :

```
public static Map<String, String> generateMapUsingPropertyFile(boolean keyNotCaseSensitive,String absolutePathToFile) throws GLDUtilException {
    BufferedReader br =null
    try {
        br= new BufferedReader (new FileReader(absolutePathToFile));
        Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        String line =null;
        while((line=br.readLine())){
```

It worked, I don't know why , but it worked.